# SQL multiple inner join databases

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join

Good morning, I am currently doing my homework and my I need to include customerID field to my table through orders. Here's my sql

```
SELECT 
    northwinds.orders.customerid, northwinds.orderdetails.orderid, 
    northwinds.products.productname, northwinds.orderdetails.unitprice,    
    northwinds.orderdetails.quantity, 
    northwinds.orderdetails.unitprice * northwinds.orderdetails.quantity AS TotalCost
FROM 
    northwinds.orderdetails 
JOIN 
    northwinds.products ON  northwinds.orderdetails.productid = northwinds.products.productid
FROM 
    northwinds.orderdetails 
JOIN 
    northwinds.orders ON  northwinds.orderdetails.orderid = northwinds.orders.orderid
```

I think I almost got it right, but it says :

> ERROR at line 4:  ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Can someone help me what do I do?

Comment: too many `From`s, there can be only one, look in your texts again at proper structure of a Select query,

Comment: You have two `FROM` clauses.  Remove the second `FROM northwinds.orderdetails`

Comment: @Siyual - That's going to cause new problems.  The second `FROM` block isn't a copy and paste of the first one, it references a different table.  ***Just*** removing that `FROM` block will cause syntax errors in the `SELECT` block; referencing a table no longer mentioned in the joins.

Comment: @MatBailie I didn't say anything about removing the entire `FROM` block.  The only thing he needs to remove is literally the second `FROM northwinds.orderdetails` bit.

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned you have two `from` statements. But please also think about using aliases and formatting code. This makes easier to notice problems. Your query should look like:

```
SELECT o.customerid
     , od.orderid
     , p.productname
     , od.unitprice
     , od.quantity
     , od.unitprice * od.quantity AS TotalCost
FROM northwinds.orderdetails od 
  INNER JOIN northwinds.products p ON od.productid = p.productid
FROM northwinds.orderdetails od 
  INNER JOIN northwinds.orders o ON od.orderid = o.orderid;
```

With such format it is easier to notice double from and amend it to final and correct version:

```
SELECT o.customerid
     , od.orderid
     , p.productname
     , od.unitprice
     , od.quantity
     , od.unitprice * od.quantity AS TotalCost
FROM northwinds.orderdetails od 
  INNER JOIN northwinds.products p ON od.productid = p.productid
  INNER JOIN northwinds.orders o ON od.orderid = o.orderid;
```

Answer (score 2):

Beside the two `FROM`  also use table alias to make it easy to read

```
SELECT o.customerid, 
       od.orderid,
       pr.productname, 
       od.unitprice,    
       od.quantity,  
       od.unitprice * od.quantity AS TotalCost
FROM northwinds.orderdetails as od 
JOIN northwinds.products as pr
  ON od.productid = pr.productid
JOIN northwinds.orders as o
  ON od.orderid = o.orderid
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query has 2 FROM clauses

```
SELECT northwinds.orders.customerid, northwinds.orderdetails.orderid,
  northwinds.products.productname, northwinds.orderdetails.unitprice,
  northwinds.orderdetails.quantity, northwinds.orderdetails.unitprice * northwinds.orderdetails.quantity AS TotalCost
FROM northwinds.orderdetails JOIN northwinds.products
    ON  northwinds.orderdetails.productid=northwinds.products.productid
FROM northwinds.orderdetails JOIN northwinds.orders
ON  northwinds.orderdetails.orderid= northwinds.orders.orderid;
```

*EDIT*

Remove the second from statement and test again. Note without the schema i don't know if this resulting query will result in a success:

```
SELECT northwinds.orders.customerid, northwinds.orderdetails.orderid,
  northwinds.products.productname, northwinds.orderdetails.unitprice,
  northwinds.orderdetails.quantity, northwinds.orderdetails.unitprice * northwinds.orderdetails.quantity AS TotalCost
FROM northwinds.orderdetails 
JOIN northwinds.products
    ON  northwinds.orderdetails.productid=northwinds.products.productid
JOIN northwinds.orders
    ON  northwinds.orderdetails.orderid= northwinds.orders.orderid;
```

Comment: That is indeed the syntactic error.  But this "answer" does not suggest how to fix that.  The second `FROM` clause is clearly an attempt to join `orders` to the existing joins between `orderdetails` and `products`.  For this to be an *answer*, rather than a *comment*, it should state ***how*** to ***correctly*** join that third table to the previous two.

Comment: I upvoted the answer.  It solves the stated problem.  Plus, StackOverflow is not a spoonfeeding forum.

Comment: @DanBracuk - No, it doesn't answer the question.  It doesn't suggest what to do.  It *implies* removing the second `FROM` block, which would cause syntax errors in the `SELECT` block *(referencing a table not mentioned in the joins)*.  And if the intention is to replace the second `FROM` block with a second `JOIN` then ***it should say that***.  This is only an observation, not a solution or an answer.  As such it is no more than a comment.

Comment: I agree this isnt an answer, but for that you have a flag and let moderators decide ;)

Answer (score 1):

your query may not have more than one "from" in it. I changed it a bit and used some aliases to make the query shorter and from my point of view more readable.

```
SELECT ord.customerid, northwinds.orderdetails.orderid, 
        prod.productname, od.unitprice, od.quantity, 
        od.unitprice*od.quantity AS TotalCost
FROM    northwinds.orderdetails od
JOIN    northwinds.products     prod ON  od.productid = prod.productid
JOIN    northwinds.orders       ord  ON  od.orderid   = ord.orderid
```

Hope that helps, take care

Andreas

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm producing my first answers and have to get used, to the Markdown.